# Any SMS blocking software without notification?

Tags: android

I have two questions:

First: I'm using TextraSMS, the app is outstanding. I just found the program has feature called SMS Blocking, does it block the SMS without notification? I receive spams everyday and if the app notifies me, it would be annoying.

Second: If not, is there any SMS or SMS blocker that meet my demand? Thanks!

Comment: One problem that I have come across is that Android let me block SMS messages from a specific __premium__ number and because they were __sent__ I still got charged even though I had blocked them!